# Save Map Themes in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, maptheme

I'm trying to save Map Themes in QGIS so that I can use them across multiple projects. Is this possible? If so, how do you do it? If not, am I missing the point of Map Themes?

I'm still trying to work out what they are for. Before coming across map themes, I had been putting layers into projects multiple times to style differently and group by map to easily make multiple maps for a project.

Comment: Map theme are used for not needing to create several project with the same data. You create a map theme for each use you need (like an 'editing data' theme, different visualisation theme, different scale printing theme, ...) and switch between them as needed. As I understand it using the same map theme on two project mean you end up with two copy of the same project. If you expend on your specific use case maybe somebody would come up with a better solution than map theme.

Comment: The easiest way would be to build new project from your main one as you have a base you like. Transferring themes could be done in theory but it would be too complicated to be worthwhile.

Answer (score 1):

The theme system in QGIS isn't really practical.
It keeps the information of symbology, labels, Attribute form, etc.

That means, if you create 2 themes, and you change the attribute on one theme, the 2 will be different (Example: if you change a field from "text" to "value map", the first theme will save the change, but not the second one ; you'll have to change it on the second theme too).
There is no theme manager.

Personally, I'm using expressions on symbology, color, etc.

But, if you want to keep a style and apply it to another layer, you can save it in the layer properties.

[image: Save style]

You'll have to make sure the layers which you apply the style have the same fields.

From the time you have your different layer styles saved somewhere, you can apply these styles in any project, and you'll have to recreate the themes everytime.

Comment: What you find not practical is intended for giving you the opportunity to have different specific use case in the same project for example for the same dataset you may have a "thematic attribute A editing" and a "thematic attribute B editing" theme each with specific symbology, attribute form that show you/let you edit only the relevant fields and each displaying the relevant base map or reference layer.